# System of equations of polynomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I came across a problem recently and I can't seem to figure out why my method isn't working. I have polynomials 
$$(q_1x^2+q_2x+q_3)(4x+7) + (q_4x^3+q_5x^2+q_6x+q_7)(9) = 1$$
And, when I expand them, I have 
$$x^3(4q_1+9q_4)+x^2(4q_2+7q_1+9q_5)+x(4q_3+7q_2+9q_6)+(7q_3+9q_7)$$
And then I made a system of equations to try and solve this.
$$4q_1+9q_4 = 0$$
$$4q_2+7q_1+9q_5 = 0$$
$$4q_3+7q_2+9q_6= 0$$
$$7q_3+9q_7 = 1$$
If I add all of the systems together, I get 
$$q_1(4+7)+q_2(4+7)+q_3(4+7)+9q_4+9q_5+9q_6+9q_7 = 1$$
or 
$$11(q_1 + q_2 + q_3) + 9(q_4+q_5+q_6+q_7) = 1$$
And this is easily solved. Just let $q_1 = 5$ and $q_4 = -6$, and the rest $0$. But when this is plugged back in,
$$(5x^2)(4x+7)+(-6x^3)(9) = -34x^3+35x^2 \neq 1$$
I realize that the coefficients sum to $1$, but why is my method of solving the system not valid? If you include the $x^n$ terms, you can divide by them and get the same thing.

Comment: Adding all the equations will only give you one condition the variables have to satisfy, not all of them.

Comment: @Tavish would it be valid to add the homogenous equations together and then have two equations, the sum of the homogenous ones and the non-homogenous one?

Comment: Yes, you can do any operation but it wouldn’t make sure that every initial condition is satisfied. If you’re just guessing solutions, make sure the initial 4 equations are true.

Comment: I'm trying to show whether or not solutions exist

Comment: One solution definitely exists. Take $q_7= \frac 19$ and the rest $0$.

Comment: Over the integers*